# how to unserialize two serialized arrays

Tags: php

I have stored more than one serialized arrays in database..lke this

```
a:2:{s:2:"B5";s:5:"user1";s:2:"B4";s:5:"user1";}a:1:{s:2:"A3";s:5:"user1";}a:1:{s:2:"A4";s:5:"user1";}
```

but when i am unserializing that arrays with

```
    $booked_seats = $r1['user_seats'];
    $b = unserialize($booked_seats);
    var_dump($b);
```

it shows me only the result of first unserialized array like this,

```
   array
  'B5' => string 'user1' (length=5)
  'B4' => string 'user1' (length=5)
```

But i want all my arrays to be unserialize..pls...support....what should i use??

Thanks.

Comment: You will need a regex to recover from that garbaged concatenation. And next time, don't store it that way.

Comment: result remains same of the first array only after using print_r($b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can we explode the concatenated serialized string with `}`?

```
$r1['user_seats'] = 'a:2:{s:2:"B5";s:5:"user1";s:2:"B4";s:5:"user1";}a:1:{s:2:"A3";s:5:"user1";}a:1:{s:2:"A4";s:5:"user1";}';
$user_seats = explode('}', $r1['user_seats']);
foreach ($user_seats as $user_seat) {
    if (strlen($user_seat)) {
        $user_seat .= '}';
        $booked_seat = $user_seat;
        $b = unserialize($booked_seat);
        var_dump($b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$serial = 'a:2:{s:2:"B5";s:5:"user1";s:2:"B4";s:5:"user1";}a:1:{s:2:"A3";s:5:"user1";}a:1:{s:2:"A4";s:5:"user1";}';
$serial=str_replace('{', '|', $serial);
$serial=str_replace('}', '|', $serial);

$p = explode('|', $serial);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($p);

$total = count($p);
$arrr=array();
for($i=0; $i<=$total; $i++){
    if(strlen($p[$i])>1){
        $arrr[$i] = $p[$i] . "{" . $p[$i+ 1]  . "}";
        $i++;
    }
}
foreach($arrr as $key => $value){
    var_dump(unserialize($value));
}
```

Result:

```
array(2) {
  ["B5"]=>
  string(5) "user1"
  ["B4"]=>
  string(5) "user1"
}
array(1) {
  ["A3"]=>
  string(5) "user1"
}
array(1) {
  ["A4"]=>
  string(5) "user1"
}
```

Comment: @CodeProtocol Can you provide the example unserialize two serialized arrays for checking purposes

Comment: `a:2:{s:8:"myentry1";s:16:"blabla}contains}";s:5:"next1";s:8:"bla}bla}";}a:2:{s:8:"myentry2";s:16:"foofoo}contains}";s:5:"next2";s:8:"foo}bla}";}` try this with your method. i serialze this array and concat `$data1 = array('myentry1' => 'blabla}contains}', 'next1' => 'bla}bla}'); $data2 = array('myentry2' => 'foofoo}contains}', 'next2' => 'foo}bla}');`

Comment: @CodeProtocol try your answer a:2:{s:8:"myentry1";s:16:"blabla{contains{";s:5:"next1";s:8:"bla{bla{";{a:2:{s:‌​8:"myentry2";s:16:"foofoo{contains{";s:5:"next2";s:8:"foo{bla{";

Comment: @CodeProtocol as example provided by me there would be no explode if using your answer